# React Hooks Equivalent of Flux Container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Refactoring a React class component previously using Flux to use React Hooks instead.

Previous component utilized getStores() and calculateState() in order to subscribe to store objects and update local state.

Is there a way to refactor the class component to a functional React component using React Hooks (useState, useEffect, etc?) to achieve the same subscription to store objects?

flux component example:

```
class exampleComponent extends React.Component {
  static getStores() {
    return [storeOne];
  }

  static calculateState() {
    const someData = storeOne.getState();

    return {
      someData
    };
  }
}
```

goal(something like this that subscribes to the store):

```
function exampleComponent(props) {
  const [storeData] = useState(storeOne.getState());

  return (
    <someElement
      data={storeData}
    >
    </someElement>
  );
}
```

Note: tried using useState as above but it does not subscribe to **storeOne**, so the component does not re-render when **storeOne** state changes. I'd like to be able to somehow subscribe to changes in **storeOne** so that the component will re-render when there are changes to **storeOne**.

Comment: This is a big question.  Here's a link to a post that explains one way of using the state hook for global state: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8 . Context is another.